# Mixing multiple data sources in the same panel

Tags: grafana

Is there a way to mix multiple data sources in the same panel (I am not interested in the same dashboard, only in the same panel)? I want the panel to have one layer with data from one data source and another layer from another data source.

Answer (score 20):

from: [What’s new in Grafana v2.5 - Mix different data sources](http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v2-5/#mix-different-data-sources)

[image]

> *In previous releases you have been able to **mix different data sources on the same dashboard**. In v2.5 you will be able to mix them on the **same graph!** You can enable this by selecting the built in `-- Mixed --` data source. When selected this will allow you to specify data source on a per query basis. This will, for example, allow you to plot metrics from different Graphite servers on the same Graph or plot data from Elasticsearch alongside data from Prometheus. Mixing different data sources on the same graph works for any data source, even custom ones.*

Comment: still possible to mix different data sources??(grafana v 6.4) @tgogos

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN From what I see at Github the Mixed Datasource should still be available (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/v6.4.3/public/app/plugins/datasource/mixed). Nevertheless I also can't find it under data sources.

Answer (score 8):

Also stumbled upon this question, using Grafana 7.3.5.
It seems the feature has been reworked a bit, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Chosing the "-- Mixed --"-entry and then adding the Datasource for every Query (in the screenshot the Datasources "temp" and "SmartHome")